A man getting turned into a robot when he gets hurt
I saw a movie (tv show?) on tv when I was a kid in the 80's.  I believe it was from the mid 80's, but I'm not sure on the date.  I remember being freaked out from watching it on TV, and a scene where they guy's legs get crushed by a door which drops down from the ceiling, and his legs turn robotic. I remember a later scene with smoke dissipating to reveal that he has been turned into a robot (I guess the gas was toxic?). I seem to remember something about him being an astronaut (maybe a scientist?) that was exposed to a gas or radiation that somehow turned him into a robot when he was hurt. I seem to remember the robot having big red eyes, but it's a fuzzy memory.  Please note it was not cartoon, and it was in color.
I'd appreciate any help identifying this show as I still remember being up all night being scared by it.

Welcome to the site! As far as identify-this questions go, this is pretty descriptive. If you remember any further details at a later stage, feel free to edit your question and add them. Hopefully you'll get the answer soon!

Thank you for the welcome. It was answered successfully.  A two and a half decade mystery SOLVED.  Thank you to the fine folks here.

You might be thinking of Infiltrator from the CBS Summer Playhouse. It is a about a scientist that turns into a robot when he's in danger. It's been years seince I've seen it so I don't remember the specific scenes you are referring to but here is the video. (It's the only recording I've found and it's pretty bad quality. It was probably copied from someones VCR recording.) 



Seems like a match. His legs get crushed by a door and turn robotic in 1:18 in this clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQM6OeWoiHs

Holy Crap.  We have a winner.  Thank you so much.  I've tried so many searches but never had enough info to get to the right answer.  In the link you posted, it's definitely the leg crush scene, and later (at 4:29) it shows the smoke and reveal of his full transformation.  I had the red eye right, but apparently there was one eye not two when he became a robot. Funny how 24 years can twist things. This is awesome.  Another childhood trauma identified by the fine folks of the internet. Best Regards.
